# What semantic notions underlie "to think; to contemplate", with "but; however; nevertheless" with "only"?

Tags: etymology

I know that [meaning 3](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%83%9F#Chinese) originates from  [忄](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BF%84) used here as the semantic component ([Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E6%83%9F#) exhibits this more clearly below). But how did 3 semantically shift to 1, 2? Their [lexical categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) all differ!

Please answer separately for 1 and 2, because even in English, 1 and 2 don't mean the same.
Their [lexical categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech) all differ!

> 1. [but](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but); [however](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/however); [nevertheless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nevertheless)
> 2. [only](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/only)
> 3. to think; to contemplate
> 4. † *Alternative form of* [唯](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%94%AF#Chinese) (*wéi*, “to be”).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Their lexical categories all differ!

That is common in Chinese, especially in Classical Chinese.

> How did 3 semantically shift to 1, 2?

Sometimes the different meanings of a character are not evolved from the same origin. In ancient times, people often designated a character with a certain meaning merely for the reason that it shares the sound of the oral language of that meaning, and so is the case.

By the way, meaning 1 & 2 were fixed over 2200 years ago (before Qin Dynasty), and there are some other characters that is interchageable with 惟 under certain meanings (listed in **bold** font).

Let me list a relatively comprehensive entry of 惟（meanings still common in modern Chinese will be intalicized）：

Original meaning:

v.

**维**：凡思（to think），即浮泛之思，寻常之思。

e.g. 惟念圣意，谛听民声。

**为**：是（be）

e.g. 不变惟何？《天演论》

***唯**：顺遂，听从（to obey, to submit）*

e.g. 惟惟诺诺=唯唯诺诺

希望，愿请（hope sb. to do sth.）

e.g. 万惟留心！《英烈传》

在于（lie in）

刑惟善察，谋惟善断。

adv.

***唯，维**：只有，单（only）*

e.g. 惟吾德馨《陋室铭》

**唯，维**：**发语词**，希望（wish）

e.g. 先王无流连之乐，荒亡之行，惟君所行也。《孟子》

conj.

即使，虽然（even if，though）

e.g. 惟信亦为大王不如也。《史记》